# Pywinauto Sendkeys function

Tags: sendkeys, pywinauto

I seem to recall that using SendKeys, you once could use the construct +(abc) to send ABC.  However, recently, that sends Abc.  Am I missing something?

By the bye, the old documentation (before ReadTheDocs) was better and more complete.  Do you have a link to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just checked `pywinauto==0.6.5` (newest) and `pywinauto==0.5.4` (early 2016). There is no difference in `SendKeys` behavior: always typing `Abc`. I'm pretty sure old 0.4.0 works the same way.

The docs can be easily compared by Contents:

- [0.6.5 docs](http://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contents.html) ("Getting Started Guide" was added, [keyboard page](http://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.keyboard.html) was also updated).
- [0.5.4 docs](http://pywinauto.github.io/docs/contents.html) with very minimal [SendKeysCtypes page](http://pywinauto.github.io/docs/code/pywinauto.SendKeysCtypes.html).

But if you want applying modifiers to the group of keys, this can be filed as an issue on GitHub. This request makes sense definitely.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I must be confusing it with a different program.  I'll file that too.  It is a good idea.